# Is there any way to make Java have the modern flat look?

Tags: java

As we all know, the flat GUI look is now becoming a thing, windows 8 has it, the now OSX and even Android are touching on it with the latest KitKat update for the call application. As Java is multiplatform there is no real look for certain OS. I absolutely love the flat look and would like to be able to use it in Java. I run a win 8 machine and love the look, but all of my Java applications that I create look odd as they don't look native to the OS. Is there any look and feels that are like windows 8?

Comment: Please take a look at [UI Windows 8 Look in JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424893/ui-windows-8-look-in-java). It may help you get started. You can search for "Metro UI", which is the name for the "flat look" for Windows.

Comment: The answer, unfortunately, is No ... at this time.  Your best bets are to keep a look out for someone developing Metro LaF classes for Java, or doing it yourself.